# how to use cocos2dx with aide on android

Tags: cocos2d-x, aide-ide

I'm new in android development. So I'm going to write small 2d game and Ichoose Cocos2d as engine. But I can't find how to use it with aide on android.Everything tutorial I found is using eclipse.Is it possible to use Cocos2d with aide on android ?
thank you!